# Using session variables with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I want to use ajax to insert a chunk of HTML/PHP. Each time it inserts it increments a variable to count how many times it has been added (tickets). I then process all the data in process.php. How can I do this? I don't want to rewrite everything in JS.

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="process.php">
<table id="dynamic_field">

<?php
$ticket = 0;
$_SESSION["ticket"] = -1;

$line = 1;
echo '  <tr>';
while($line <= 7) {
  $number = 1;
  while($number <= 5) {
    echo'<td><input id="num" name="num'.$ticket.$line.$number.'" maxlength="2" size="1" value="'. ${"num".$ticket.$line.$number}.'"></td>';  
    $number++;
  }
  echo'<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked'.$ticket.$line.'"></td>';
  $line++;
echo'  </tr>';
}
echo'  </br>';

echo'<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">Add</button></td>';

echo'</table>';
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>



<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<?php session_start(); $_SESSION["ticket"]++;  $line = 1;
echo '  <tr>';
while($line <= 7) {
  $number = 1;
  while($number <= 5) {
    echo'<td><input id="num1" name="num'.$ticket.$line.$number.'" maxlength="2" size="1" value="'. ${"num".$ticket.$line.$number}.'"></td>';  
    $number++;
  }
  echo'<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked'.$ticket.$line.'"></td>';
  $line++;
echo'  </tr>';
}
echo'  </br>';

?>');  
      });  
 });
```

Comment: `$('#dynamic_field').append('<?php session_start();.... etc` ??? you are aware of the differences between clientside and serverside code? What's wrong with some more javascript?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of serverside and clientside, not sure why you're asking. I'm fine with more JS, I mean I don't want to rewrite everything in JS. All I need is the ability to count the number of times the Ajax adds another ticket. So simply a counter on the Ajax that can be assigned to a variable for me to use in the POST validation.

Comment: To note, the <?php session_start(); $_SESSION["ticket"]++; is desperation of me trying to get it to work.
I need the   name="num'.$ticket.$line.$number.'" to be represented as name="num011" for example for the post. So I need to be able to increment the value of ticket somehow with each Ajax call.

Comment: have you had any luck trying the demo - did it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To aid you solve your problem I quickly cobbled together a simple demo which, when studied and dissected, should help you find your solution I hope.

There is no `jQuery` because I don't use it - instead there are some basic vanilla javascript functions and some very simple PHP.

The overview is upon initial pageload the session variable is created with the default value of zero. There is a simple `event listener` assigned to the button which, when clicked, will trigger the ajax request. The ajax request is processed by PHP which increments the counter and sends back some html content.

```
<?php
    /* start a session */
    session_start();

    /* create the variable to count tickets */
    if( empty( $_SESSION['tickets'] ) )$_SESSION['tickets']=0;

    /* process ajax request - increment session variable and send some html back for the callback to mangle */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action']=='add-ticket' ){

        ob_clean();


        /* increment the counter */
        $_SESSION['tickets']++;



        /* send some new HTML back with content */
        exit( 
            sprintf(
                '<tr>
                    <td>%d</td>
                    <td>%s</td>
                </tr>',
                $_SESSION['tickets'],
                date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' )
            )
        );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>PHP Sessions and Tickets</title>
        <script>
            const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onload=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                };
                xhr.onerror=function(e){
                    alert(e)
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.send( buildparams( params ) );
            };
            const buildparams=function(p){
                if( p && typeof( p )==='object' ){
                    p=Object.keys( p ).map(function( k ){
                        return typeof( p[ k ] )=='object' ? buildparams( p[ k ] ) : [ encodeURIComponent( k ), encodeURIComponent( p[ k ] ) ].join('=')
                    }).join('&');
                }
                return p;
            };




            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
                let bttn=document.querySelector('input[type="button"][name="add"]');
                let tbl=document.querySelector('form > table');
                let span=document.querySelector('div > span');

                bttn.addEventListener( 'click', function(e){
                    ajax.call( this, location.href,{ action:'add-ticket' }, function(r){
                        tbl.querySelector('tbody').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', r );
                        span.innerText++;
                    })
                },false );
            },false );

        </script>
        <style>
            table{width:80%;border:1px solid black;float:none;margin:auto;}
            th,td{padding:1rem;text-align:center;background:white;}
            input{width:100%;padding:1rem;margin:1rem auto}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Ticket Count</th>
                    <th>Datetime</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type='button' name='add' value='Add Ticket' />
        </form>
        <?php   
            printf( '<div>The current ticket count is: <span>%d</span></div>', empty( $_SESSION['tickets'] ) ? 0 : $_SESSION['tickets'] );
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing thanks @RamRaider  ! Think this will work perfectly thanks :)